Any easy way to get boxed \implies arrows?
Trying to write my math solutions and I'm looking for a boxed \implies arrow as in the photo.

I'm looking to separate out the 'if' and 'only if' implications in my proofs so suggestions that make that easy to see in latex are more than welcome.
Thanks!

I would recommend making it clear with words which part of the proof you are in. But if you prefer the boxed arrows, here's a very low-tech solution.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand{\Onlyifstep}{%
  \begingroup
  \fboxsep=1pt
  \raisebox{1.2ex}{\fbox{\raisebox{-1.2ex}{$\Rightarrow$\hspace{-0.05em}}}}%
  \endgroup
  \hspace{0.5em}%
  }
\newcommand{\Ifstep}{%
  \begingroup
  \fboxsep=1pt
  \raisebox{1.2ex}{\fbox{\raisebox{-1.2ex}{\hspace{-0.05em}$\Leftarrow$}}}%
  \endgroup
  \hspace{0.5em}%
  }

\begin{document}

\Onlyifstep \kant[1]

\Ifstep \kant[2]

\end{document}



It's just a question to decide a balance.
The parameters used in the definition of \bipml may need to be changed according to the math font you use.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\bdirect}{\bimpl{\Rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\binverse}{\bimpl{\Leftarrow}}

\newcommand{\bimpl}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \raisebox{0.6\depth}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
    $\boxed{{#1}\rule{0pt}{1.2ex}}$%
  }\enspace
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Donkeys can fly if and only if unicorns exist.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
We divide the proof in two steps.

\bdirect Suppose donkeys can fly. Then unicorns can fly as well 
add text to the proof add text to the proof
add text to the proof add text to the proof.

\binverse Summon a unicorn. Then 
add text to the proof add text to the proof
add text to the proof add text to the proof.
\end{proof}

\end{document}



With newtx we'd get

Changing the definition to
\newcommand{\bimpl}[1]{%
  \noindent
  \raisebox{0.5\depth}{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
    $\boxed{{#1}\rule{0pt}{1ex}}$%
  }\enspace
}

seems better

Experiment with your setup.
